# Direct sum of a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am currently reading a proof that involves some result from functional analysis which I would like to understand a little better -

Suppose we have a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a closed linear subspace $\mathcal{L}$ in $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose further that we are given that $\mathcal{L}$ contains the span of two sets $P_1$ and $P_2$ which are orthogonal, and conversely the span of these sets contains $\mathcal{L}$. The orthogonality statement means that if $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product in $\mathcal{H}$ then
\begin{equation}
(f,g) = 0 \quad \forall f \in P_1 \text{ and }  g \in P_2
\end{equation}
Then it follows that both Span$(P_1)$ and Span($P_2$) are closed, and we have an orthogonal sum
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \text{Span}(P_1) \oplus \text{Span}(P_2)
\end{equation}

My background in functional analysis is very sketchy unfortunately, I would like to understand what are the general results that I need to know about in order to see this conclusion as being trivial?

In particular, why do I need closure of $\mathcal{L}$ to deduce that it has this direct sum decomposition ? Does this not follow directly from the fact that  Span$(P_1)$ and Span$(P_2)$ are orthognal ?  Also, how do I deduce these two spaces are closed from the fact that $\mathcal{L}$ is closed ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being closed in $\mathcal{H}$, $\mathcal{L}$ is itself a Hilbert space. By construction, you have that $\text{Span}(P_1)$ is the orthogonal complement of $\text{Span}(P_2)$, hence it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the complete inner product spaces, the following facts are assumed to be known by the reader:

- *A closed subspace of a complete space is complete.* Hence $\mathcal{L}$ is complete, and the inner product can be restricted on $\mathcal{L}$ and makes $\mathcal{L}$ a Hilbert space.
- *There exists an orthonormal basis for any Hilbert space.* This tells us that the span of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is the span of the orthonormal bases residing in these two sets respectively.

Now that if
$$
(f,g) = 0 \quad \forall f \in P_1 \text{ and }  g \in P_2
$$
by contradiction we could see that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not share any common basis, otherwise choose $f$ and $g$ be that common basis would make above inner product be 1.

By the orthogonality of the orthonormal basis we could see:
$$
\text{Span}_{\alpha\in A, \beta\in B}\{e_{\alpha},e_{\beta} \}  = \text{Span}_{\alpha\in A}\{e_{\alpha}\} \oplus \text{Span}_{\beta\in B}\{e_{\beta}\}
$$
if $A$ and $B$ share no common index for the basis. And this is where the direct sum comes from. For more read about the decomposition of Hilbert space like this, please refer to [this link](https://planetmath.org/BestApproximationInInnerProductSpaces).